# Installing Ember-CLI: How to give write access to Read-only file system (ubuntu)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ember.js, vagrant, ember-cli

I am trying to install ember-cli in my vagrant box:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:/vagrant$ sudo npm install -g ember-cli
```

All is looking good until it checks the file permissions:

```
WARN engine ember-cli@2.11.0: wanted: {"node":"0.12.* || ^4.5 || 6.* || 7.*"
(current: {"node":"4.2.6","npm":"3.5.2"})
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib
```

Then after that, a bunch of error lines are being displayed:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-47-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ember-cli"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-47-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ember-cli"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log.2125708066
npm ERR! code ETXTBSY
npm ERR! errno -26
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! ETXTBSY: text file is busy, rename 'npm-debug.log.2125708066' -> 'npm-debug.log'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /vagrant/npm-debug.log
```

I tried searching for the fix but still out of luck. I'm planning to use ember-cli together w/ Rails and used the Vagrantfile here: https://gorails.com/guides/using-vagrant-for-rails-development

Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this? I really think I am missing something here.

Update:

I tried giving a write access to the folder but still getting this:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:/vagrant$ sudo chmod -R 777 '/usr/local/lib'
chmod: changing permissions of '/usr/local/lib': Read-only file system
chmod: changing permissions of '/usr/local/lib/python3.5': Read-only file system
chmod: changing permissions of '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages': Read-only file system
chmod: changing permissions of '/usr/local/lib/python2.7': Read-only file system
chmod: changing permissions of '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages': Read-only file system
chmod: changing permissions of '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages': Read-only file system
```

Comment: Can You show the permissions for /usr/local/lib on current user?

Comment: don't know what are the current permissions, what command should I enter in terminal to get it?

Comment: ls -ld /usr/local/lib

Comment: The problem is with Your user, somehow You don't have the permissions to write in that catalogue

Comment: Here's what I got: drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Feb  4 13:00 /usr/local/lib

Comment: I think the best way for now is to create a new sudoer, I'm not really sure how to fix it

Comment: try [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), it allows to use node and npm under regular user, without sudo. Also, you may not succeed if your project is in shared folder and your host system is windows, because windows uses NTFS and NTFS doesn't support permissions used in linux. I moved my development to VM completely because of such issues (created normal VM with 100GB drive, installed IDE and everything I need and work from there)